# Creating a codebook in R that considers non-labelled variables

Tags: r, purrr, r-haven

I found a useful and simple function which creates a codebook for .dta datasets in R, the code is the following:

```
codebook <- map_df(dt, function(x) attributes(x)$label) %>% 
  gather(key = Code, value = Label) %>% 
  mutate(Type = map_chr(dt, typeof),
         Mean = map_dbl(dt, mean, na.rm = T),
         Prop_miss = map_dbl(dt, function(x) mean(is.na(x))))
```

The function works just fine, unless there are variables in the dataset that are unlabaled, in that case it doesn't. I would like to modify it so that it also reports variables with no labels as "UNLABELED" along with the rest of the information.  I tried something like this:

```
if (map_df(dt, function(x) attributes(x)$label) == NULL) {
   attr(function(x) dt$(x), "label") <- "NO LABEL"
}
```

But it doesn't work (I am not really skilled with coding on R).
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The `if/else condition would be inside

```
library(purrr)
map_dfr(dt, ~ {
          if(is.null(attributes(.x)$label)) {
                attr(.x, "label") <- "NO LABEL"
         }
         attributes(.x)$label})
```

Comment: Thank you, there is a small typo in your code, but this works:
`library(purrr)
map_dfr(dt, ~ {
          if(is.null(attributes(.x)$label)) {
                attr(x, "label") <- "NO LABEL"
         }
         attributes(.x)$label})`

Comment: @tommasocrosta sorry, couldn't pinpoint the typo.  Can you please specify the place where it is a typo

Comment: `library(purrr) map_dfr(dt, ~ {           if(is.null(attributes(.x)$label)) {                 attr(.x, "label") <- "NO LABEL"          }          attributes(.x)$label})`
There is a missing .